# def issue - NameError: name ' passwordchecker' is not defined

Tags: python

I am making a password checker and a generator with a menu, the password checker by it's self works fine but the menu does not work along with the code and I've tried the menu by it's self and that does not work either. These are the errors that I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jasiu Czajka/PycharmProjects/untitled/First Code.py", line 41, in <module>
    mainmenu()

  File "C:/Users/Jasiu Czajka/PycharmProjects/untitled/First Code.py", line 24, in mainmenu
    passwordchecker()
NameError: name 'passwordchecker' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, so please help if you can.

I use pycharm and python 3.6.3

```
import re


def mainmenu():
    print("*******************************************************************")
    print("           Welcome to the Password Checker & Generator             ")
    print('*******************************************************************')
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This program can be used to check a password to see if it is strong")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This Program can be used to generate strong passwords")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("1. Password Checker")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("2. Password Generator")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("3. Exit")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("*******************************************************************")
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(input("Enter choice:  "))  # Making selection a variable
            if selection == 1:
                passwordchecker()
                break
            elif selection == 2:
                passwordgenerator()
                break
            elif selection == 3:
                exit()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
                mainmenu()

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
    exit()


mainmenu()


def passwordchecker():
    print("***************************************************************")
    print("                       PASSWORD CHECKER                        ")
    print("***************************************************************")
    print("                                                               ")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The password must be at least 8 characters, and a maximum of 24")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The password must at least have 1 number in it")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print('The password must have at least 1 symbol')
    print("Allowed Symbols: !, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, -, +, =, ")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

    incorrectpassword = True

    while incorrectpassword:
        password = input("Type in your password: ")
        if len(password) < 8:
            print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long")
        elif len(password) > 24:
            print("Your password must be maximum 24 characters long")
        elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
            print("You need a number in your password")
        elif not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
            print("You need a capital letter in your password")
        elif not any(i.islower() for i in password):
            print("You need a lowercase letter in your password")
        elif re.search('[!, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, -, +, =,]', password) is None:
            print("You need a symbol in your password")
        else:
            print("Your password has all the characters needed")
            incorrectpassword = False


passwordchecker()
mainmenu()


def passwordgenerator():
    print("Work In Progress")
```

Comment: In `mainmenu()` you're calling `passwordchecker()` which is defined below. add   `passwordchecker()`  function above  `mainmenu()`

Comment: @JasiuCzajka He's trying to say that you're invoking a function before you've actually defined it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def passwordchecker():

    print("***************************************************************")
    print("                       PASSWORD CHECKER                        ")
    print("***************************************************************")
    print("                                                               ")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The password must be at least 8 characters, and a maximum of 24")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The password must at least have 1 number in it")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print('The password must have at least 1 symbol')
    print("Allowed Symbols: !, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, -, +, =, ")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

    incorrectpassword = True

    while incorrectpassword:
        password = input("Type in your password: ")
        if len(password) < 8:
            print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long")
        elif len(password) > 24:
            print("Your password must be maximum 24 characters long")
        elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
            print("You need a number in your password")
        elif not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
            print("You need a capital letter in your password")
        elif not any(i.islower() for i in password):
            print("You need a lowercase letter in your password")
        elif re.search('[!, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, -, +, =,]', password) is None:
            print("You need a symbol in your password")
        else:
            print("Your password has all the characters needed")
            incorrectpassword = False


def mainmenu():
    print("*******************************************************************")
    print("           Welcome to the Password Checker & Generator             ")
    print('*******************************************************************')
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This program can be used to check a password to see if it is strong")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This Program can be used to generate strong passwords")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("1. Password Checker")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("2. Password Generator")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("3. Exit")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("*******************************************************************")
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(input("Enter choice:  "))      # Making selection a variable
            if selection == 1:
                passwordchecker()
                break
            elif selection == 2:
                passwordgenerator()
                break
            elif selection == 3:
                exit()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
                mainmenu()

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
    exit()


mainmenu()
passwordchecker()
mainmenu()


def passwordgenerator():

    print("Work In Progress")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your *call* to `mainmenu()` to below the definitions for `passwordchecker()` and `passwordgenerator()`. Otherwise, they won't be defined when `mainmenu()` tries to call them.

```
import re


def mainmenu():
    print("*******************************************************************")
    print("           Welcome to the Password Checker & Generator             ")
    print('*******************************************************************')
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This program can be used to check a password to see if it is strong")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This Program can be used to generate strong passwords")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("1. Password Checker")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("2. Password Generator")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("3. Exit")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("*******************************************************************")
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(input("Enter choice:  "))      # Making selection a variable
            if selection == 1:
                passwordchecker()
                break
            elif selection == 2:
                passwordgenerator()
                break
            elif selection == 3:
                exit()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
                mainmenu()

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
    exit()




def passwordchecker():

    print("***************************************************************")
    print("                       PASSWORD CHECKER                        ")
    print("***************************************************************")
    print("                                                               ")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The password must be at least 8 characters, and a maximum of 24")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("The password must at least have 1 number in it")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print('The password must have at least 1 symbol')
    print("Allowed Symbols: !, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, -, +, =, ")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

    incorrectpassword = True

    while incorrectpassword:
        password = input("Type in your password: ")
        if len(password) < 8:
            print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long")
        elif len(password) > 24:
            print("Your password must be maximum 24 characters long")
        elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
            print("You need a number in your password")
        elif not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
            print("You need a capital letter in your password")
        elif not any(i.islower() for i in password):
            print("You need a lowercase letter in your password")
        elif re.search('[!, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, -, +, =,]', password) is None:
            print("You need a symbol in your password")
        else:
            print("Your password has all the characters needed")
            incorrectpassword = False


passwordchecker()


def passwordgenerator():

    print("Work In Progress")

mainmenu()
mainmenu()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have called some functions before they were defined. Place passwordgenerator() and passwordchecker() before mainmenu() and then call them as you please.

Also, may I suggest putting this program in a loop, and
make that loop dependent on a variable. It would be much more elegant that way. Second, rename your functions like:

```
mainMenu()
passwordGenerator()
passwordChecker()
```

It looks more professional. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't fix anything. The problem is that `mainmenu()` is being called before `passwordchecker()` and `passwordgenerator()` are defined, which still happens in your code.

Comment: Ahh. I did not realize mainmenu () called those two. Thank you! Editing now.